# Wordpress Redirects Old Post Url to New Related Post

Tags: redirect

I have a post with a URL of example.com/x-y-z/ and when I added a completely new post with a new URL of example.com/x-y-a/, WordPress redirects the old URL to the new post's URL.
(I don't want any redirection as those are similar in subject but completely different posts which should be default behaviour)

I use the permalink structure as example.com/post-name/ structure.